# ImportError: cannot import name memoize

Tags: python, django, importerror

I have a little problem with project upgrade from Django 1.7.1 to 1.9.0.
Every 'RemovedInDjango20Warning' has been fixed, but one thing still left and I don't know how to deal with it.

When I'm trying to visit any page, there is always an ImportError like:

```
 **TemplateSyntaxError at /auth/**

 'crispy_forms_tags' is not a valid tag library:
 ImportError raised loading crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_tags: 
 cannot import name memoize***
```

I have included `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` in my template site, and added 'crispy_forms' in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

I tried to find any solution, but without success, before the update worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1.9 is not released, in fact it is not even near a release date. So what you are actually running is the latest master. Why? Why not use the released 1.8?

Comment: Hmm It is a good question why, just I installed 1.9. and forgot to check information about that version. Is there any chance to fix it in 1.9 or I need a downgrade?

Comment: Okay so, I made a downgrade to 1.8 and everything works well... Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error, as has been stated, is that Django dropped memoize at some point, so the version of crispy-forms you were trying to use was not working with the Django version.

Solutions include trying a different version of Django, or trying a different version of crispy-forms. If you are using an unreleased version of Django, then there may not be a version of cripsy that supports it (yet).

However, your error ("cannot import name memoize"), can show up for released versions of Django - I had that error, and a search lead me to this ticket. The issue was that i was using an old version of crispy (1.4.1), and a recent version of Django (1.11.1).

To find a version of crispy to use, you can check the github release page:

https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/releases

The release comments include some information about the Django version supported by different releases.