# ImportError: cannot import name memoize 1.8-1.9

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-crispy-forms

I have an error:

> Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_field': cannot import name memoize

Downgrade to 1.8 did not help like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308267/importerror-cannot-import-name-memoize)

It was worked on Ubuntu 14.04, but doesn't work on Win10

- Python2.7
- Django1.9
- django-crispy-forms==1.4.0

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Internet\DJANG\django19\django19\newsletter\views.py", line 45, in home
    return render(request, "newsletter/home.html", context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
    template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 26, in get_template
    engines = _engine_list(using)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 143, in _engine_list
    return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 110, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 101, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 31, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 49, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 131, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 148, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_field': cannot import name memoize
[12/May/2016 18:26:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 109450`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import name memoize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186660/cannot-import-name-memoize)

Comment: You asked this 2 hours ago, for which there was already a duplicate.

Comment: I changed the duplicate target on the other question, because the [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308267/importerror-cannot-import-name-memoize/30308791#comment61912691_30308791) was written before Django 1.9 was released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crispy forms 1.4 is out of date.

If you look at the [crispy forms changelog](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md), you can see when compatibility for different Django versions was added.

For Django 1.8 you need to install crispy forms 1.5 or later.

For Django 1.9 you need to install crispy forms 1.6 or later.

Comment: upgraded crispy to 1.6 and nothing happens

Comment: Make sure you have restarted the server after upgrading. If it still doesn't work, update your question with the **full** traceback.

Comment: I don't see how crispy forms 1.6 can give you that error. The loading of the template tag is hiding the problem so we can't see where the import is failing. Does it work If you try `from crispy_forms.templatetags import crispy_forms_field` in the shell?

Comment: No, there is the same error:    from django.utils.functional import memoize
ImportError: cannot import name memoize

Comment: Please show the traceback for that failed import. It should never happen on crispy forms 1.6 with Django 1.9, because the `lru_cache` import above will work. See the [source code](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/1.6.0/crispy_forms/compatibility.py).

Comment: from crispy_forms.templatetags import crispy_forms_field
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templatetags\crispy_forms_field.py", line 11, in <module>
    from crispy_forms.utils import TEMPLATE_PACK
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.utils.functional import memoize
ImportError: cannot import name memoize

Comment: That traceback does not match the [source code](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/1.6.0/crispy_forms/utils.py#L11) for crispy forms 1.6. You must have an earlier version installed.

Comment: Yes. you are right, it's because I have Python 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Your version of django-crispy-forms is outdated, this has been fixed. Update it by running:

pip install django-crispy-forms -U

Comment: Sure it is outdated, it is now 4 years old.